# PHP Array - Removing Items and subsequent array loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a web page which allows users to add a particular record as a 'Favourite' - as part of this process it adds the select record ids to an array as follows:

```
array_push($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'], $recid);
```

and they can also un-favorite records which removes them from the array:

```
if (($key = array_search($recid, $_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'])) !== false) {
 unset($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'][$key]);
}
```

As a result the array might look like this:

```
[selectedArticleIDs] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1398
            [2] => 851
            [3] => 1635
            [4] => 65
            [5] => 860
        )
```

I then do a find to group all the selected favourites into a list as follows:

```
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs']); $i++) { 
        ${'findreq' . ($i+1)} = $fm->newFindRequest('Articles');
        ${'findreq' . ($i+1)}->addFindCriterion('RecordID', $_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'][$i]);
        $request->add($i+1, ${'findreq' . ($i+1)});
        }
```

The problem occurs when someone un-favourites an item - you can see in the above example there is no:

```
[1] => 1234
```

array item, which throws the for loop out when performing the find as it skips the last item in the array (`860` in the above example).

I can see what the problem is here but not sure how to go about fixing this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Rather than `unset`, you should consider using [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array-splice) so that keys are re-numbered appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways you can fix it.

You can use `foreach` instead of `for` loop

```
$i = 1;
foreach($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'] as $favourite){
    ${'findreq' . $i} = $fm->newFindRequest('Articles');
    ${'findreq' . $i}->addFindCriterion('RecordID', $favourite);
    $request->add($i, ${'findreq' . $i});
    $i++;
}
```

Or, you can use `array_values` which will re-index the array

```
$selectedArticleIDs = array_values($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs']);
for($i = 0; $i < count($selectedArticleIDs); $i++) { 
  ${'findreq' . ($i+1)} = $fm->newFindRequest('Articles');
  ${'findreq' . ($i+1)}->addFindCriterion('RecordID', $selectedArticleIDs[$i]);
  $request->add($i+1, ${'findreq' . ($i+1)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreach` loop for that.

```
foreach($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'] as $i => $v) { 
    ${'findreq' . ($i+1)} = $fm->newFindRequest('Articles');
    ${'findreq' . ($i+1)}->addFindCriterion('RecordID', $v);
    $request->add($i+1, ${'findreq' . ($i+1)});
}
```

If it will not solve the problem then you have to add the if condition to check that whether the key is exit or not. I am not sure that you are containing in `$fm` object.

Answer (score 0):

The array_search call is unneeded overhead, you can remove it, the effect is the same.
You shouldn't worry about the key. Instead of the for loop, use a foreach.

```
$i = 1;
foreach($_SESSION['selectedArticleIDs'] as $selectedArticleID) {
    ${"findreq$i"} = $fm->newFindRequest('Articles');
    ${"findreq$i"}->addFindCriterion('RecordID', $selectedArticleID);
    $request->add($i, ${"findreq$i"});
    $i++;
}
```

Do you really need variable variable names? I think you should try to avoid it.